# iOS 7 onchange event is broken in iPad 3+Mini // Need work around

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, events

**Please test this only on iPad running ios 7**

It appears that iOS 7 doesn't support alert() and confirm() for onchange events on iPad. Strange thing is that it works on iPhone 4s running ios 7.0 and in desktop browser but not on ipad 3 or ipad mini running ios 7.0. It fires the dialog and when clicked it darkens the button (as if it was clicked) and then the browser freezes. Happens in both Safari and chrome running on iOS 7 iPad and iPad mini.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Already tried onblur and onkeypress with no success :-/

```
Options
<select id="iCard" onchange="alert('It worked.')">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">(none)</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="4">Option 4</option>
</select>
```

Issue can be seen here (make sure to test it on iPad running iOS 7): http://jsfiddle.net/sethsanders/MvSxm/

Comment: Some comments on breaking changes in iOS7 - also states here that the alert, confirm and prompt aren't working in full screen web apps: http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/safari-ios7-html5-problems-apis-review hopefully you won't have to wait for an update

Comment: Thanks Adam, I came across that article when researching this issue. However, we are not running it as a home screen web app. It is just running through safari (or Chrome) like the jsFiddle above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Workaround here http://jsfiddle.net/sethsanders/ZzkBd/

It is very IE7 to need a setTimeout to handle a stuck event handler

```
function SetCard(sel) {
   setTimeout(function() { alert('SetCard called successfully.');},10);
   document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML=sel.value + ":" + sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it's an iOS7 bug on the iPad only.

The HTML's select on iPad looks as the popup (iOS developers use the *popover* notion) on selecting.

I'm sure the point is in the conflict of two modal controls – select's popup and the confirm/alert. I.E. the confirm/alert appears at the time when select's popup is still visible and this locks up the confirm/alert.

Exactly that happened in your case for *onchange* event.

The *setTimeout* helps in that case:

```
<select id="iCard" onchange="setTimeout(function(){ alert('It worked.'); })">
```